# How to get more than once install referrer receiver in the AndroidManifest

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

I am a game designer and unity3d developer with an average Android development knowledge, basically in the game am working on, the client want to integrate certain services (voluum, heyZapp and Tapjoy) that each of them require the following receiver in the manifest file :

Voluum :

```
<receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.voluum.sdk.VoluumForwardingBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

HeyZap :

```
<receiver android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.PackageAddedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="package" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

TapJoy :

```
<receiver android:name="com.tapjoy.InstallReferrerReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Before integrating TapJoy, Voluum & HeyZap services were working correctly even with two receivers, but after adding TapJoy, the tapJoy tool keep showing this error :

> More than one InstallReferrerReceiver are configured. Please check
>   Assets/Plugins/AndroidManifest.xml

Am thinking this is because both Voluum & TapJoy has the same intent-filter right ? is there a workaround for this problem ?

In one of the [tapJoy documentation page](http://dev.tapjoy.com/sdk-integration/android/how-to-use-multiple-install-referrer-receivers/), they specifically highlighted this problem with this manifest example :

```
<receiver android:name="com.tapjoy.InstallReferrerReceiver" android:exported="true">
 <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
 </intent-filter>
 <meta-data android:name="OtherReceiver1" android:value="com.example.OtherReceiver1"/>
 <meta-data android:name="OtherReceiver2" android:value="com.example.OtherReceiver2"/>
</receiver>
```

So i tried to follow what they did and merged TapJoy & voluum receivers like this :

```
<receiver android:name="com.tapjoy.InstallReferrerReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:exported="true" android:name="voluum" android:value="com.voluum.sdk.VoluumForwardingBroadcastReceiver" />
    </receiver>
```

**EDIT: the following quote has been fixed**

> But now i can't even install the game, 1st the icon is not showing,
>   instead there is the default Android package icon, and when i try to
>   install the game it shows this error :
>
> > There is a problem parsing the package

Now the error i get is this when initializing Voluum SDK:

[image]

Finally, just in case you needed it, here is the entire Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" package="com.publisherCompany.lines" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:name="com.soomla.SoomlaApp">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
        <!-- Google Play -->
        <!--            -->
        <!--            -->
        <meta-data android:name="billing.service" android:value="google.GooglePlayIabService" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!-- End Google Play -->
        <!--            -->
        <!--            -->
        <!--            -->
        <!--            -->
        <!-- voluum 
        <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.voluum.sdk.VoluumForwardingBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>-->
        <!-- End voluum -->
        <!--            -->
        <!--            -->
        <!-- HeyZap -->
        <!-- adClony -->
        <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyOverlay" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <!-- End adClony -->
        <!-- chartboost -->
        <activity android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:excludeFromRecents="true" />
        <!-- End chartboost -->
        <!-- Applovin -->
        <meta-data android:name="applovin.sdk.key" android:value="sbF7fJhkR0VfbTLbqNDyeid0pi2bTuxKUBR8U8sw8LZkvwKkHTfxFHy3_-eTtaoLmDUFLL9UhkDadXJw5-sKGo" />
        <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinConfirmationActivity" />
        <!-- End Applovin -->
        <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapInterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapVideoActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapProxyActivity" />
        <!--<activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.VASTActivity" />-->
        <receiver android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.PackageAddedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="package" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- End HeyZap -->
        <!--            -->
        <!--            -->
        <!-- Others -->
        <activity android:name="com.mobilefuel.sdk.AdInterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:label="AD" android:exported="false" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true">
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="\ 503591776472556" />
        <!--End Others -->
        <!-- TapJoy activities -->
        <activity android:name="com.soomla.store.billing.google.GooglePlayIabService$IabActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.TJAdUnitActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.mraid.view.Browser" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.mraid.view.ActionHandler" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.tapjoy.appstore" android:value="Google" />
        <receiver android:name="com.tapjoy.InstallReferrerReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:exported="true" android:name="Voluum" android:value="com.voluum.sdk.VoluumForwardingBroadcastReceiver" />
        </receiver>
        <!--End TapJoy activities -->
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
</manifest>
```

**EDIT** removing this line from the Voluum receiver

```
<action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
```

allowed me to install the game and get the new sdk (tapjoy) working properly, but now Voluum is not being called at all

Thank you all and have a good day

Comment: Might I suggest you edit your post to remove your private SDK keys?

Comment: Did you try remove `android:exported="true"` from `<meta-data android:name="Voluum" android:value="com.voluum.sdk.VoluumForwardingBroadcastReceiver" />` ?

Answer (score 1):

Design a common receiver which can than triggers all others as your need.

```
public class ManyInstallTrackersReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     InstallReferrerReceiver mixpanelReferrerTracking = new InstallReferrerReceiver();
     mixpanelReferrerTracking.onReceive(context, intent);
     // Now you can pass the same intent on to other services,
     // or process it yourself
   }
}
```

Then, in your AndroidManifest.xml, you can refer to this class instead of Voluum, Tapjoy, Blabla whatever you want:

```
<receiver
  android:name="my_great_package.ManyInstallTrackersReceiver"
  android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action
     android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```